# Adding multiple layers from an array in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a lot of OpenLayers layers that change every day so instead of having to create, and change a long list of these:

```
var layerone = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ("mylayer1", "mylayer1/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", { });

var layercool = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ("mylayer1", "mylayer1/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", { });
```

etc

I'd like to first make an array of layer names:

```
var mylayers = new Array("layerone","layercool","layeryo","layerhello");
```

and then create all these layers in a for loop, something like this:

```
var length = mylayers.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

mylayers[i] = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ("mylayers[i]", "mylayers[i]/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", { }); 

}
```

How do I first of all create unique var names for each layer in the foor loop and then do the loop? I read somewhere to use `window[layers[i]] = new OpenLayers.Layer...` or maybe `eval`? but I'm not sure how to access these later on when doing the `map.addLayers();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get your added layers by `map.getLayersByName('layerone')`. and you can give layerId to your layer so you can get them all.

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
mylayers[i] = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(mylayers[i], mylayers[i] + "/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {
              layerId : i
 }); 

map.addLayer(mylayers[i]);

};
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Yes! Works like a charm. I was close with my own code but not all the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An update using OpenLayers 3.

In this example, data is first parsed from an external php file (foo.php) using $.getJSON, placed into an array of objects, and added to the map through $.each iterations.  Example shown is for a kml file, but can be adapted for any ol.Layer construct.

```
(function get_layers() {
    $.getJSON(
        "foo.php",
        function(data) {
            var jsArray = (data);  
            $.each(jsArray, function(key, value) {
                var layer = value.baz;  //baz as a value in the array 
                var url = value.buz;  //buz as a value in the array 
                var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                    source: new ol.source.Vector({
                      url: url,
                      format: new ol.format.KML(),
                    })
                }); 
                map.addLayer(userLayer);
            }) 
         } 
    )
})();
```

The closing () are for automatic loading of the function, which may or not be needed depending on your use.